GeoServer unable to render WFS
I´m using a fresh and empty installation of GeoServer 2.25.3 and try to publish an external WFS-Server. The original Source-URL of the WFS is: https://www.wfs.nrw.de/geobasis/wfs_nw_alkis_vereinfacht?
I have no problems in adding the external URL as new datastore and even the menu for publishing individual layers works fine, the bounding box can be detected and all feature types are shown correctly.
But if i try to request the WFS or even as WMS in my GeoServer, I get an error code 400.
The original Source-URL works fine via direct call in QGIS. Does anybody know what could be wrong?

what does the log file show? and if you increase logging to GEOTOOLS-DEV what then?

400 means the syntax of the request is wrong, so how are you  requesting the cascaded WMS/WFS?
